# Parent Div height not increasing according to child div?

Tags: html, css

Parent div isn't adjusting its height with respect to child's height.
Is there any better way to do that in CSS alone? If not any other.

Here is the **[Fiddle!!](http://jsfiddle.net/5GB7k/)**

```
#view_container {
    z-index: 9; 
    background: cyan;
    clear: both;
    width: 463px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `overflow:hidden` to `#view_container`

```
#view_container{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/5GB7k/1/)

Comment: Seems like **`#comment_body`** height is not increased?
Btw thanks for your reply.

Comment: `overflow: auto` can also be used, in case `hidden` is undesirable. @Fastnto See if removing the `height: 85px` rule from `#comment_body` fixes it.

Comment: @Hiral Can you give an explanation how this overflow hidden is working over here ? I know that overflow hidden is only for hiding scroll bar

Answer (score 0):

you can also go for the following code,which can be an alternative. Add a class called clearfix to your div and apply the following css.

```
.clearfix:after {
   content: " "; /* Older browser do not support empty content */
   visibility: hidden;
   display: block;
   height: 0;
   clear: both;
}
```

Comment: I didn't get you, can you please elaborate??